# How to Sign X.509 certificate with RS256 in PHP? Not able to get Valid fingerprint...x5t

Tags: php, x509certificate, x509, fingerprint, jwt

I have implemented JWT token generator library from [Here](https://github.com/F21/jwt/blob/master/JWT/JWT.php), and i am able to get RS256 Token (Payload).
But i am having issue with Header data:
I need one header value "x5t", which is not generated from the given library.
I need header data like:

```
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "x5t": "COm8ON2SD2MTc5jwcxZ0vE3-XJo"
}
```

I am getting first two parameter successfully, but not able to get valid third parameter.

My Sample code is :

```
$fingerprint = str_replace("SHA1 Fingerprint=", '', system('openssl x509 -noout -in my.pem -fingerprint'));
$fingerprint = sha1($fingerprint);
$fingerprint = base64_encode($fingerprint);
$fingerprint = rtrim(strtr($fingerprint, "+/", "-_"), '=');
```

To generate Valid "x5t" parameter there is already code available in .NET, need to convert in PHP.

Thanks for watching my question.
Any suggestion welcomed.

Comment: nice. i face same issue since 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.6, you can use the following function [`openssl_x509_fingerprint`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-fingerprint.php):

```
$cert = openssl_x509_read($certificate);
$sha1_hash = openssl_x509_fingerprint($cert); // sha1 hash (x5t parameter)
$sha256_hash = openssl_x509_fingerprint($cert, 'sha256'); // sha256 hash (x5t#256 parameter)
```

If you do not have PHP 5.6, you can generate this fingerprint by yourself using the content of your certificate file (begins with `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and ends with `END CERTIFICATE`):

```
function sha1_thumbprint($file_content)
{
   $file_content = preg_replace('#-.*-|\r|\n#', '', $file_content);
   $bin = base64_decode($file_content);
   return hash('sha1', $bin);
}
```

Do not forget to encode in Base64 Url Safe the result.

```
$encoded_fingerprint = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($fingerprint), "+/", "-_"), '=');
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I am using PHP 5.4.30 version.
So, need to update it to try your given solution...
Let me try it.

Comment: You do not need to update! I gave you a function for older PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

`system` outputs its result directly, unless you use the optional second parameter, which puts the result into the variable.

So use

```
system('openssl x509 -noout -in my.pem -fingerprint', $sha1);
$fingerprint = str_replace("SHA1 Fingerprint=", '', $sha1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: Thanks for answering : I am using that technique from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426927/php-ssl-certificate-fingerprint

Comment: My issue is How to generate x5t parameter?

Comment: I have also tried that but it was not create VALID x5t parameter..
It will generate like "MDg6RTk6Qjk6Mzg6REQ6OTI6MEY6NjM6MTM6NzM6OTg6RjA6NzM6MTY6NzQ6QkM6NEQ6RkU6NUM6OUE"
and i want like "COm8ON2SD2MTc5jwcxZ0vE3-XJo"

Answer (score 0):

`openssl_x509_fingerprint` (which Florent Morselli mentioned) returns an sha1 hash of the DER encoding of the cert. eg.

```
<?php
$cert = '...';

echo openssl_x509_fingerprint($cert);
echo "\r\n<br />\r\n";
echo sha1(base64_decode(preg_replace('#-.*-|\r|\n#', '', $cert)));
```

They output the same thing. At least with this cert:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

`openssl_x509_fingerprint` is only on PHP 5.6 so if you're PHP 5.5 or earlier you can use the alternative method instead.